# Create executable for private npm module written in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npx

I am trying to create an executable for use with `npx`. I have package.json with the relative information like so -

```
 ...
 "name": "@company/example-command",
 "bin": {
    "example-command": "./dist/index"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prepare": "tsc && chmod +x ./dist/index.js"
  },
  ...
```

Everything publishes correctly to the Github registry. However, upon invocation,

```
npx @company/example-command
```

I am getting an error

```
no such file or directory, chmod /path/to/npx/modules/@company/example-command/dist/index
```

This seems to indicate that `npx` is finding the correct command and downloading the relevant package, but the executable is not added to the path.

My hunch is that I need to compile the typescript lib to `dist` before invoking the file (`tsc && ./dist/index`), but I assumed that `prepare` would handle the set-up of the `dist`.

What is the proper way to make this Typescript lib into a `bin` that is executable by `npx`?

Comment: are u using npm link ??

Comment: I am not. I forgot the extension on `index.js`!  It is now working :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

`.bin` path is not in a node context, so it needed the explicit `.js` extension

```
"example-command": "./dist/index.js"
```